# ExtJS column layout, move resizable panels without overlap

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, panel, overlap

I’m trying to achieve something like this (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/portal/portal.html) but I want the portlets to be resizeable.

So I have a Ext.TabPanel with a Ext.layout.ColumnLayout layout.
All items are panel (Ext.form.Panel) with:

```
resizable : true,
draggable:true,
```

Specifically, given a initial situation like the following

[image: initial situation]

I would like to be able to drag the highlighted portlet to a new position and have the other portlets “to make room” for it. Unfortunately, what I get right now is

[image: real situation overlap]

i.e. two portlets overlap. I would like to get this instead (no overlapping):

[image: desired situation no overlap]

So the question is: is there a way to achive this without requiring the columns to have a fixed size?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you extending the demo or are you building a portal yourself?

Comment: I'm not extending the demo, I'm developing from scratch, because (looking the souce code) the demo have column layout with fixed columns number and size, and doesn't allow to use resizable panels.

Comment: Alright, you know you ask for alot here because overlapping is the expected functionality on draggable panels. I can't provide the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really simple.
All you need is to handle move event, for example in the controller of your custom panel:

```
 move:function( thi, x, y, eOpts ){
    if(x!=0 && y!=0)
    {
        var cont = thi.getBubbleParent();
        var xNew = thi.getPosition()[0];
        var yNew = thi.getPosition()[1];

        var ind = 0;
        while(cont.items.items[ind].getBox().y+cont.items.items[ind].getBox().height < yNew)
        {
            ind++;
        }
        while(cont.items.items[ind].getBox().x+cont.items.items[ind].getBox().width < xNew)
        {
            ind++;
        }
        thi.setPagePosition([(xNew-x),(yNew-y)]);
        cont.insert(ind,thi);
    }
}
```

The position of all other panels are automatically managed from your column layout.